# How to disable "Audio Player" to show up on the main page

Tags: audio

I have a post with audio player with autostart enabled, and i decided to put it in the beginning of the post, before putting "read more" excerpt feature. So the problem is, that audio player plays music on the main page, but i want it to work only on post page. Is it possible to do?
I've put my post in drafts for now, until i solve this little problem...

Comment: By post page do you mean "single post" page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to put the audio player *after* the read-more link.

If that would prove cumbersome (e.g. you've already got too may posts with audio players), you could try hooking into the `the_content` filter, and remove the audio player if not on a single-post view. e.g.:

```
function mytheme_remove_audio_player_from_home( $content ) {
    // is_singular() is true for 
    // single posts, pages, and attachments
    if ( ! is_singular() ) {
        // do something, such as a str_replace() or 
        // whatever else would be appropriate, to
        // filter out the audio player markup
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'mytheme_remove_audio_player_from_home' );
```